# Why does changing alpha over a white background yield a different result than mixing with white?

Tags: css, sass

So I'm playing with colours in SCSS and I noticed a strange behaviour that I assume is strange to me because I don't completely understand how the alpha channel works.

Given a background colour (I'll use white for convenience), why do the following two colours seem different?

```
rgba(blue, 0.5); // over a white background
mix(blue, white, 50%)
```

Change the values or the colours to any arbitrary value and the problem persists.

The problem I'm trying to solve: some of my elements have an opacity smaller than 1 and now they also need to appear over dark backgrounds and I want to keep the same colour (e.g. a semi-transparent blue over a white background) even when they're set above a dark background.

---

For a little demonstration, here are the values obtained by both of these methods:

- `rgba(blue, 0.5)` compiles to `rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5)` and measured over white background reads `#8491FD` (macOS chrome)
- `mix(blue, white, 50%)` compiles to `#8080ff` and when measured on screen w/ a color picker reads `#8184FC` (macOS chrome)

```css
.rgba {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5);
}

.mix {
  background: #8080ff;
}

body {
  background: white;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2em;
}
```

```html
<span class="rgba">rgba: #8491FD</span>
<span class="mix">mix: #8184FC</span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might not be the answer you're looking for but colors on the web are famously imprecise. This is why we're seeing new specs recently, with new color value functions `hsl`, `hwb`, `lch`, `lab`, `device-cmyk` and new display capabilities media queries like `color-gamut` and `dynamic-range`.

Sass is old and doesn't care about all that and I wouldn't be surprised if their color math wasn't even close to being correct (and there is probably a lot of scientific literature on mixing colors on a digital media with different ways of doing the maths).